# ¿Cómo puedo convertir este script en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

```
create table producto ( 
    codigo number(4) constraint pk_producto primary key, 
    nombre varchar2(100) not null, 
    precio number(7), 
    stock number(5), 
    categoria number(3), 
    constraint chk_precio check (precio > 0),
    constraint fk_producto_categoria foreign key (categoria)
        references categoria(id)
);
```

Comment: No se entiende tu pregunta. Eso es una instrucción SQL que puedes pegar en tu phpmyadmin o directamente en la consola de MySQL y que te va a crear una tabla en la base de datos que estés usando en ese momento. ¿A que te refieres con que es un script y que lo quieres convertir a MySQL?

Comment: cuando lo pego en php admin me tira este error                                                    Se encontraron 4 errores durante el análisis.

    Tipo de dato desconocido. (near "number" at position 34)
    Se esperaba una coma o un corchete de cierre. (near "constraint" at position 44)
    Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "100" at position 99)
    Tipo de declaración desconocida. (near "not null" at position 104)

Comment: de donde has sacado esa consulta?  para que tipo de base de datos es?  porque no parece para mysql, pues el tipo **number** no existe.

Comment: me la pasaron para un ejercicio pero no entiendo como usarla en mysql

Comment: Tiene pinta de ser una consulta para una base de datos de Oracle, donde allí si existe ese tipo **number**.  En MySQL debes usar INT para los enteros, o FLOAT para los decimales (hay más tipos, pero con esos dos ya te valdrá).

Comment: con los constraint me lanza error tambien no entieno muy bien como usar la tabal en my sql

Comment: El `varchar2` tampoco es de MySQL, ese lo cambias por `varchar` a secas.

Comment: algo asi?----create table producto ( 
 codigo int(4) 
        constraint pk_producto primary key, 
 nombre varchar(100) not null, 
 precio int(7), 
 stock inr(5), 
 categoria int(3), 
 constraint chk_precio check (precio > 0),
 constraint fk_producto_categoria foreign key (categoria)
  references categoria(id)
);

Comment: Yo lo haria así para salir del paso y que te cree la tabla, y después ya la afinarás con el phpmyadmin:  `create table producto ( 
    codigo int(4) primary key,
    nombre varchar(100) not null,
    precio int(7),
    stock int(5),
    categoria int(3),
    chk_precio float,
    fk_producto_categoria int (4))`

Comment: Seguramente el precio te interesa que sea FLOAT y no INT por los decimales (si es que en tu ubicación usais decimales para vuestra moneda)